# Android Asyntask for web service

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I'am developing an application which is totally based on fetching data from web services.
In one activity I have to call almost 5 6 different web services which displays different information. This application is target v 2.3 to 4.x, as there are no network communication allowed on main ui thread so I am making  5 6 AsyncTask classes, because its post execute helps me a lot in displaying.

Now I am confused is this approach right or wrong, making 5 6 AsyncTask classes(can't reduce the number of web services or call in one AsyncTask because I have to check data again and again). Is this a good approach or should I change my pattern, and then switch to what approach.
Using this approach my application is working very nice and smooth on all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a good pattern. It fits nicely into Object-Oriented design and each one performs it's own task.

If your web calls are all directly after each other, you could combine them into one huge AsyncTask if you really want to. That would definitely reduce the nice encapsulation you have now and would make it a lot harder for someone to maintain and debug down the line.

It sounds like what you have is good already, and if it's working well, why fix what's not broken.

Comment: thanks I just wanted to make sure that this approach is right

Comment: I've just been thinking through the same issue. I've got 3 web calls that are all pretty similar and I was thinking of making a more general AsyncTask that could handle all 3, but then decided against it.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that each ASyncTask class is an API request to the webservice, if so it is the right way of doing it. Any network operation should be done outside the UI thread.

There is also a better way of using ThreadPools to limit the number of Server requests you want to keep active at a time.